# How to play video from ftp streaming file?

Tags: android, ftp, video-streaming

If found many tips about how to stream from classic url link, but nothing about ftp.
Is it the same way to proced ?

Thanks you.
AL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's media framework only supports HTTP and RTSP for streaming. You will need to download your file and play it back, or use some alternative URL that offers HTTP or RTSP for the media file.

Comment: Ok, but can I play it before is completly downloaded, or do I have to wait until it's completely download ?
Thanks.

Comment: @nonozor: You have to wait until it is completely downloaded. As I wrote, Android's media framework only supports HTTP and RTSP for streaming.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an app in android, there is a player for android which will allow streaming from a ftp server. it's called FIPE Video Player. It's free, neat and stream in high quality. 
Update: another brilliant app (again if you are looking for an app) I recommend is ES File Explore, which also allows streaming from ftp server instead of downloading locally and then playing.

Answer (score 2):

Just use VLC for Android and add your FTP as a source.
See : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=fr&gl=US

Answer (score 0):

I use the following software to stream videos directly from FTP server

- Android:    **x-plore File Manager**
- MacOS:  **Infuse player**
- iOS:  **Infuse player** or **FE File Explorer**
- Windows:    **Mountain Duck**

All of this apps allow to connect to FTP server, retreive list of video files (with thumbnails) and play/stream videos from FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pretty simple ftp server for android(wifi FTP),i use a PRO version .On my android TV i use KODi there is ftp client and everything work like charm.It's a verry good combination.Try it ;)